# How bad is the transit security queue at IST airport

Tags: transit, airport-security, short-connections, turkish-airlines, isl

I am quite worried about my transit timing at IST airport. I will be flying Doha-IST-Dubai on a single ticket but the connecting time at IST is only 1 hr 20 mins. I heard that the transit security has a massive queue and if you miss your connecting flight if the flight landed over 60 mins, Turkish Airlines will not help you.

I wonder if anyone has experienced the transit security queue at 6.00 pm. How busy is it? Also there is the fast track service that costs approx 170 Euro PP, which is super expensive but cheaper than buying a new ticket. Has anyone used them?

Comment: This time should be enough for your layover. However, if you see that you are late as a result of a queue, you can always ask the airport workers or just skip the queue.

Comment: If there's no way you could've made the connection, the airline has to help you - 60 minutes or not. That said, ask staff.

Answer (score 1):

The queues can be long and look daunting but they move fast and I would not worry. Last time I transited there was in fact around 6 pm, on a Monday, two-three months ago. I had 1 hr 45 to make the connection and there was plenty of time left to look around, buy a fruit juice and sit down for some time (finding a seat and getting the wifi to work on the other hand was more difficult).

Comment: My flight is also on a Monday lol. I hope it will be the same as yours, or less.

Comment: Just in case, that wifi will need an active cell connection that can receive an SMS for the free time limited package